# What type of insect is this orange-camouflaged creature?

Tags: bug-identification, thailand

The picture below was taken at the [Royal Flora Ratchaphruek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Flora_Ratchaphruek), a park with lots of flowers and vegetatation in Chiang Mai, Thailand. Can anyone identify the bug I found there, shown in the picture below?

[image]

Comment: looks super cute :3 I wanna pet it gently

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a species of longhorn beetle called [Aristobia approximator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristobia_approximator). There are two or three different species that live in my region but I wasn't familiar with this particular one which is quite impressive looking. Since it seems to feed on teak, this has to be an Asian species.